# Core Data. ...is not key value coding-compliant for the key "(null)"

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have this error after saving entites (DictionaryMarketSubcategoryEntity), than saving them again.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<DictionaryMarketSubcategoryEntity 0x60000269e2b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: the entity DictionaryMarketSubcategoryEntity is not key value coding-compliant for the key "(null)".'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8004278cb __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff80004dba3 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80042753d -[NSException init] + 0
    3   CoreData                            0x00007ff8049b8a02 -[NSMergePolicy _mergeToManyUnionRelationshipsForObject:andObject:] + 945
    4   CoreData                            0x00007ff8049bcf29 -[NSMergePolicy resolveConstraintConflicts:error:] + 5412
    5   CoreData                            0x00007ff8049bb99a -[NSMergePolicy resolveConflicts:error:] + 210
    6   CoreData                            0x00007ff80497a534 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 3215
    7   FCDev                               0x0000000101624e04 $s5FCDev13CoreDataStackC20saveContextIfChangedyyF + 1524
    8   FCDev                               0x0000000101573f8b $s5FCDev36CoreDataStorageServiceImplementationC5writeyyF + 43
    9   FCDev                               0x0000000101575710 $s5FCDev36CoreDataStorageServiceImplementationCAA0dE0A2aDP5writeyyFTW + 16
    10  FCDev                               0x0000000100a02291
```

Here is entity (DictionaryMarketSubcategoryEntity) that I save. It has child subcategories (DictionaryMarketSubcategoryEntity). If I comment and remove child, then everything OK. It seems that when I save array of DictionaryMarketCategoryEntity it save child entities (DictionaryMarketSubcategoryEntity) and after resaving them, the merge policy give a crash. Why?

[image]

Here is code of init:

```
extension DictionaryMarketCategoryEntity: JSONInitializable {
    convenience init(json: JSON) {
        self.init(context: AppInstances.shared.storage.context)

        self.backgroundColor = json["backgroundColor"].stringValue
        self.backgroundImagePath = json["backgroundImage"].stringValue
        self.descriptionText = json["description"].stringValue
        self.icon = json["icon"].stringValue
        self.id = json["id"].stringValue
        self.imagePath = json["image"].stringValue
        self.parent = json["parent"].stringValue
        self.span = json["span"].int16Value
        self.title = json["title"].stringValue
        self.type = json["type"].stringValue

        let childrenJson = json["children"].arrayValue
        let childrenEntities = childrenJson.map { DictionaryMarketSubcategoryEntity(json: $0) }
        let childrenSet = NSSet(array: childrenEntities)
        addToChildren(childrenSet)
    }
}

extension DictionaryMarketSubcategoryEntity {
    convenience init(json: JSON) {
        self.init(context: AppInstances.shared.storage.context)

        self.id = json["id"].stringValue
        self.title = json["title"].stringValue
        self.descriptionText = json["description"].stringValue
        self.imagePath = json["image"].stringValue
        self.backgroundImagePath = json["backgroundImage"].stringValue
        self.backgroundColor = json["backgroundColor"].stringValue
        self.icon = json["icon"].stringValue
        self.parent = json["parent"].stringValue
        self.span = json["span"].int16Value
        self.type = json["type"].stringValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Some code could help here, are you working with different contexts for instance and if so how?

Comment: Why post some json related code, isn't this an issue when saving to Core Data or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added the parent relationship in `subcategory`. Then in main entity using `addToChildrenEntities` - the autogenerated by xcode function. After that the error has gone. It's not because the JSON. It seems that core data fail to merge if child entity (subcategory) doesn't know what is his parent entity.